# Generic Automapper MappingProfile registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper, generic-programming

I have hundreds of classes that I need to repeat same logic to register the mapping (traditional). Is there a one line solution (using generic)?

Here is what I have tried. Can't figure out how to implement the `HasProperty` method and to set the lamba expression property `.[prop]`

```
public class Person
{
   public string ID{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public DateTime Birth{get;set;}

   public class _Profile:AutoMapper.Profile{
     public _Profile(){
       /*traditional way*/
        CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.ID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ID))
         /*omitted for brevity*/
        .ReverseMap();
           /*  Generic way*/
            BaseModelMappingConfigurator
            .RegisterBaseModelMap(CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>,true);
     }
   }
}
```

here is the `RegisterBaseModelMap` method implementation

```
     public static void RegisterBaseModelMap<TSource, TDestination>
              (Func<IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination>> createMap, 
     bool reverse = true)
    {
        var mapCreator = createMap();
        var properties = typeof(TSource)
     .GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | 
                       System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
     foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            if (typeof(TDestination).HasProperty(prop))
            {
                mapCreator.ForMember(dest => dest.[prop], 
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.[prop]));
            }
        }
        if (reverse) mapCreator.ReverseMap();
    }
```

Comment: To use reflection to automate Automapper mapping configuration, which is intended to avoid reflection when mapping entities. It's cool! :)

Comment: AM can do [that](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Inline-Mapping.html) for you. But this only really works in simple cases.

Comment: Its really not clear what you are trying to do? **Auto**Mapper is called that way because it **AUTOMATICALLY** does bind properties by convention (same name, flattened names). For this cases, all you need is `CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>()`. You only need `.ForMember` etc. **only** when when its **not covered** by the conventions. So messing with reflection you gain **nothing** thats not available out of the box

Comment: @Tseng please add this as answer so I can accept it. Thank you!